# Page abstract in the end of my document

Tags: header-footer, abstract

```
\begin{document}
\include{Introduction}
\include{Chapter1}
\include{Chapter2}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}
\include{Abstract}
\end{document}
```

I have a question: I added the abstract in my document as shown before, but I'd like that the abstract page has no number; however, the header "Bibliographie" appears in this page. How can I remove it?

Comment: i have tested your solution but it deletes the header and the number page of the last page of the bibliographie.. have you an idea please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\cleardoublepage \pagestyle{empty}` as in

```
\begin{document}
\include{Introduction}
\include{Chapter1}
\include{Chapter2}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}
\cleardoublepage 
\pagestyle{empty}
\include{Abstract}
\end{document}
```

to get rid of the headers in the abstract.